# Price Floors and Subsidies

Tags: price, subsidies

Why would a government choose to impose a price floor for agricultural commodities when subsidies would prove to be more beneficial for not only consumers, but also the government itself, since they would not have buy up the surplus and then price it lower if they want to export it?